# sh.exe": http-server: command not found

Tags: node.js, github, npm, httpserver

After I ran following command

```
npm install
```

it was successfully executed
But when i tried to execute following command

```
http-server
```

It gave following error

```
sh.exe": http-server: command not found
```

Can somebody help me out to solve the above error

Comment: So what do you expect should happen?

Comment: when I execute the command git bash should display Starting up http server . serving ./ on port 8080  hit cntr +c to stop the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed the http-server package locally, rather than globally.

Check the node_modules/.bin/ folder, find the executable and execute that.

If that works try `$(npm bin)/http-server` if you are running from git bash. If you use the windows command prompt try `node_modules\.bin\http-server.cmd` from the same folder where you ran npm install

Comment: Thank you for reply                                                                               There are no executable files in node_modules /bin folder

Comment: I edited my answer. When you ran `npm install` was there a packages.json file in the folder from which you ran it? In that files is http-server listed somewhere?

Comment: After i ran $(npm bin)/http-server  sh.exe": c:\Users\pkottawa\angularjs\node_modules\.bin/http-server: No such file
 or directory so http-server file is not present here

Comment: Install http server first then. Run `npm install http-server`. This will download the binaries/libs. After that you should run `$(npm bin)/http-server` to run the binaries. Run all commands from same folder.

Comment: I did install server but still getting errors pkottawa@PKOTTAWA-LAP ~/angularjs (master)
$ $(npm bin)/http-server
sh.exe":  No such file
kottawa@PKOTTAWA-LAP ~/angularjs (master)
$ http-server
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1129:14)
    at listen (net.js:1155:10)
    at net.js:1253:9
    at dns.js:85:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3

Comment: dont run  `$(npm bin)/http-server sh.exe`, just run `$(npm bin)/http-server`

Comment: i ran `$(npm bin)/http-server` I got error `sh.exe": c:\Users\pkottawa\angularjs\node_modules\.bin/http-server: No such file
 or directory` even after installation http-server file is missing

Comment: Looking at the EADDRINUSE in your error, it means that the port on which the server is trying to listen is already in use.

Comment: You mean port conflicts ? If so I've to change port number for http-server

Comment: How do I modify the port number ? Which file Can you please guide me @Zasz

Comment: Looking at [https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server] you will need to pass in -p argument. Like this: `$(npm bin)/http-server -p 8081`

Comment: Also check task manager, for other node.exe processes, and kill the node.exe processes you dont need. It could be the case that one of your previous runs of http-server is blocking the port. http-server (and all other node packages) runs under the name of node.exe in task manager

Comment: `$(npm bin)/http-server -p 8081` it worked Thanks a lot